# How to 'bind' in Javascript without changing the context of 'this'?

Tags: javascript, constructor, closures, this

I have a constructor and a closure.

My Constructor Function:

```
var Item = function(data) {
  this.sayThis = function() {
    console.log(this);
  };
  this.data = data;
};
```

My Closure Function:

```
var $item = function(document, window, ..., itemData) {
  return new Item(itemData);
}.bind(dontWannaPutAnythingHere, document, window, .../*except itemData*/);
```

If i use anything at 'thisArg', the context of 'this' inside the newly formed object tends to be what ever is given. I don't want that, but still I want to bind those document, window and stuff, so that I can provide the last argument item data at some other time.

I am gonna call a new function as

```
// Calling it normally.
var someItem = $item("chocolate");
// This should result in Item {data: "chocolate", ...}
// and not anything else.
var someItem = $item("chocolate").sayThis();
```

Cheers,
Rj

Comment: The term you are looking for is "partial application".

Comment: Actually the function on which you are calling `bind` does only execute `return new Item(itemData);` and not use `this` at all, so it is irrelevant what you pass for the thisArgument. Just use `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot bergi. Yes I wan going to use this closure to create jQuery like objects, that can have variables that live in an isolated enviroment.  -cheers, Rj

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
 var Item = function(data) {
  this.sayThis = function() {
    console.log(this);
  };
  this.data = data;
};

var $item = function(document, window, itemData) {
  return new Item(itemData);
}.bind(null, document, window);

// Calling it normally.
var someItem = $item("chocolate");
// This should result in Item {data: "chocolate", ...}
// and not anything else.
var someItem = $item("chocolate").sayThis();
```

Does it meet your requirements?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/sfcakq2j/4/

Comment: Yup, sorry to bother for such a small thing. Thanks a looot!! though Seb. Have a great day and a Happy New year. TC

Comment: I would have used `undefined` since it is the default null value. In addition for that last statement to work `sayThis` (and other methods) should have a `return this` as the last statement when there is no apparent return value so that the object can chain methods as in the last statement.

Comment: beware, this doesn't work if you `'use strict'`; then this will be `null`

Answer (score -1):

`bind(null, ...)` won't work if you `'use strict'` mode in your code. Why don't you use a [iife](/questions/tagged/iife), instead of `bind`?

```
var $item = (function(document, window){
    return itemData => new Item(itemData);
})(document, window);
```

Comment: Of course binding to `null` does work, why wouldn't it?! And notice that the IEFE does something very different than `bind`.

Comment: #Thomas Well can you pass an argument later if you didn't now using IIFE? I personally think it isn't possible. Since an IIFE simply executes right then it is of no use to me. I don't know anything about the 'strict' mode though. I will try it in strict mode and confirm - cheers, Rj